# Puppeteer and jnode multiple async call returning the same result when ending the same time

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I'm developing a **scraper**/crawler using Node and Puppeteer. I'm trying to run several crawlers at the same time. Each one access a different site, login and do stuff. At the end all on them return a json with data. When an error occurs, the method returns a json with "N/A" on the fields.

The main file:

```
var a = require('./a');
var b = require('./b');
var c= require('./c');
var d= require('./d');

const http = require('http');
var url = require("url");

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
        var urlObj = url.parse(request.url, true);

       // cnpj is the company id I want my scraper to look for.
        if (urlObj['query']['cnpj'] != undefined) {
            var cnpj = urlObj['query']['cnpj'];

            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.writeHeader(200);
          
            getCotacao(cnpj).then(ret => {
                response.end(JSON.stringify(ret));
            })

        }
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 404;
        response.end();
    }
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');



async function getCotacao(cnpj) {
    var returnCount = 4;
    var sleepCycle = 0;

    var ret = [];

// run all of them
        a(cnpj).then(response => { console.log('Ended a:' + JSON.stringify(response)); ret = ret.concat(response); returnCount--; });

    b(cnpj).then(response => {   console.log('Ended b:' + JSON.stringify(response)); ret = ret.concat(response); returnCount--;   });

    c(cnpj).then(response => {   console.log('Ended: c:' + JSON.stringify(response)) ; ret = ret.concat(response); returnCount--;  });

    d(cnpj).then(response => {    console.log('Ended d:' + JSON.stringify(response)) ; ret = ret.concat(response); returnCount--;   });

    //wait them to finish or not
    while (returnCount > 0 && sleepCycle < 90) { // 1:30m timeout. After the timeout or all promises returned, end the code. Which ever comes first 
        await sleep(1000).then(function () {
            sleepCycle++;
            console.log("sleepCycle: " + sleepCycle);
        });
    }

    return ret;
}
```

My a, b, c methods look all the same:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const a= async (cnpj) => {
        var browser;
        try {
            var timeout = 3000; // 7 segundos
            browser = await puppeteer.launch(
                {   headless: true
                }
            );
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('a_website.com', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: timeout});
            await page.waitForSelector('#txtLogin', {timeout: timeout});
            await page.focus('#txtLogin');
            await page.keyboard.type('my_login');
            await page.focus('#txtSenha');
            await page.keyboard.type('my_pass');
            await page.click('#btnLogin');
            await page.waitForSelector('#btnSic', {timeout: timeout});
            await page.click('#btnSic');
            await page.waitForSelector('#txtCnpj', {timeout: timeout});
            await page.focus('#txtCnpj');
            await page.keyboard.type(cnpj);
            await page.click('#btnAnalisar');

            await page.waitForSelector('#Finaliza', {timeout: timeout});

            const CreditLimit = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#Finaliza > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2) > span').textContent);
            const RiskRate = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#Finaliza > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > span').textContent);
            const limitAvailable = "";

            data = {
                'a':
                    {
                        CreditLimit,
                        RiskRate,
                        limitAvailable
                    }
            }


            await browser.close();
            return data;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            data = {
                'a': {
                    'CreditLimit': 'N/D',
                    'limitAvailable': 'N/D',
                    'RiskRate': 'N/D'
                }
            }
            if (browser)
                await browser.close();

            return data;
        }
};

module.exports = a;
```

THE PROBLEM: Sometimes (not always :) ) when I run it and one of the methods (a,b,c or d) get puppeteer timeout and finishes, close to the time when another method also finishes, both of them get the same return on the .then() clause. A log of this is:

```
sleepCycle: 1
sleepCycle: 2
sleepCycle: 3
sleepCycle: 4
{ TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 3000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:674:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at a (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\src\a.js:15:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'TimeoutError' }
{ TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 3000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:674:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at b(C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\src\b.js:21:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'TimeoutError' }
sleepCycle: 5
{ TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#idToken1" failed: timeout 3000ms exceeded
    at new WaitTask (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:561:28)
    at DOMWorld._waitForSelectorOrXPath (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:490:22)
    at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:444:17)
    at Frame.waitForSelector (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:628:47)
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at Page.waitForSelector (C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:1089:29)
    at c(C:\Users\fabyt\PhpstormProjects\robo_garantia\src\c.js:16:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'TimeoutError' }
Ended a:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
Ended b:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
Ended c:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
sleepCycle: 6
sleepCycle: 7
sleepCycle: 8
sleepCycle: 9
sleepCycle: 10
Ended d:{"d":{"CreditLimit":"1.000.000.00","limitAvailable":"R$ 1,000,000.00","RiskRate":"1.5000"}}
sleepCycle: 11
```

The important part is here:

```
Ended a:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
Ended b:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
Ended c:{"c":{"CreditLimit":"N/D","limitAvailable":"N/D","RiskRate":"N/D"}}
```

Notice that the .then() clause of method a,b and c have all returned the same json from the method c. Like somehow one method could access other methods return promise. When the puppeteer code doesn't break each method return it's right json. The problem only occurs when one or more then one method timesout. How can I fix it?

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrapper. ‘To scrap/scrapper’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `data` inside the modules has not been declared anywhere, so it is global. All the modules access the same memory area, so the values get overriten.